# Android studio 2.0 preview 6,7,8,9

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

whenever i click on build in android studio 2.0 preview 6-9 give me these errors 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/7C88771C8876D45C/Android Workplace/Spinner/Spinner/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.1.1/jars/libs

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/7C88771C8876D45C/Android Workplace/Spinner/Spinner/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.1.1/jars

etc  each time i click run i get these errors and after 4-5 times its magically start building app and install it i don't know why it is not running at first build up to preview 5 android studio 2.0 was working like a charm ...now disappointed can any one help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this problem too. Try to killing java process. It's helped me a lot

Comment: killing java process what do you mean ? can u please elaborate ?